# Single Stream and Multiple Subscribers

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, java-9, reactive-streams

I'm testing the waters with Java9 reactive streams and RxJava2. I dont really have a preference on either but am looking for some guidance on if this is possible.

1. I'm creating a pre-configured amount of subscribers like so:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i<MAX_SUBSCRIBERS; i++) {  
        System.out.println("Creating subscriber: " + i);  
        publisher.subscribe(new MySubscriber<>(i + "-subscriber"));   
   }
   ```
2. I'm reading in a list of files from a directory for the purposes of concurrent uploads to some 3rd-party system.

   ```
   Stream<Path> paths = Files.list(Paths.get("/my/dir/with/files"));
   paths
   .filter((Files::isRegularFile))
   .forEach(pathName -> publisher.submit(pathName.toString()));
   ```

I'm receiving the following output:

```
    0-subscriber: /my/dir/with/files/test0.txt received in onNext
    0-subscriber: /my/dir/with/files/test1.txt received in onNext
    1-subscriber: /my/dir/with/files/test0.txt received in onNext
    1-subscriber: /my/dir/with/files/test1.txt received in onNext
```

Ideally, we should see the following behavior. Each subscriber should be performing work on a unique file.

```
    0-subscriber: /my/dir/with/files/test0.txt received in onNext
    1-subscriber: /my/dir/with/files/test1.txt received in onNext
```

Is this possible? Any tips would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

This was a comment, but it became too long. It's not a real answer, though, because I'm no reactive stream expert. It's rather some food for thought.

My understanding is that each subscriber sees all published elements and that subscribers should be independent of one another (which I'd say excludes explicit coordination). If there is a material difference between the files (say one is PDF the other TXT), then subscribers might decide to only act on the types they were built for, but otherwise, each should process each element.

It looks like you're trying to spread the workload across several subscribers, which I assume run in different threads. That's definitely something existing concurrency constructs handle extremely well. Have a look at [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), for example.

That said, if you're building a larger stream pipeline, I see no argument against encapsulating the distribute-file-processing-across-threads part in a single subscriber. It might even be a publisher itself, publishing the result of processing each file once that's done.

A final caveat: Maybe RxJava has something up its sleeves for this specific use case. I'm curious to read other answers.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 9 Flow API consist of 4 interfaces and the `SubmissionPublisher` class which dispatches every submitted value to all of its `Subscriber`s. There are no JDK tools currently to support your dataflow.

In contrast, RxJava is a rich fluent library with hundreds of operators where you can perform parallel processing without duplication:

```
    ParallelFlowable<Path> pf = 
            Flowable.<Path, Stream<Path>>using(
                () -> Files.list(Paths.get("/my/dir/with/files")),
                files -> Flowable.fromIterable((Iterable<Path>)() -> files.iterator()),
                AutoCloseable::close
            )
            .parallel(2)
            .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile);

pf.subscribe(new Subscriber[] {
    new MySubscriber<>("0-subscriber"),
    new MySubscriber<>("1-subscriber"),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Publishers can be of two kinds: multicast and unicast. Multicast publishers feed each subscriber with the full set of messages, while unicast publishers route each message to single subscriber. `SubmissionPublisher` is programmed as multicast, it is said in its documentation.

You can find implementations of unicast publishers in my library [DF4J](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j). Look for implementations of the interface `org.df4j.protocol.Flow.Publisher`, which extends `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`